# Why does SwiftUI automatically disable all buttons when dismissing a sheet and then changing the NavigationPath?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This example consists of a simple NavigationStack leading to `Subview`. The latter displays `SomeSheet` which, when its button is tapped, dismisses itself and changes the NavigationPath in order to go back to `ContentView`.

The mechanism works perfectly. However, all the buttons in `ContentView` are automatically disabled ([example in video](https://i.imgur.com/b4C63Se.mp4)). Why does this happen? Is it a SwiftUI bug?

```
enum Root: Hashable {
    case subview
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $model.path) {
            List {
                Button("Some button") {} // FIXME: All ContentView buttons are disabled when SomeSheet's button is tapped
                NavigationLink(value: Root.subview) {
                    Text("Go to Subview")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Root.self) { _ in Subview() }
        }
        .environmentObject(model)
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    @MainActor final class Model: ObservableObject {
        @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    }
}

struct Subview: View {
    @State private var sheetIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show sheet") { sheetIsPresented = true }
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented) { SomeSheet() }
    }
}

struct SomeSheet: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: ContentView.Model
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Dismiss and go back to ContentView") {
            dismiss()
            model.path.removeLast()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 14.0 (iOS 16).

Comment: With Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.0 I am not able to reproduce this issue but we do have such an issue in some other project where a few tap gestures don't get fired at all.